# Help with a PNP Switch

Tags: switches, voltage-divider, pnp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm8VBu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to design a simple switch for a electric valve. I'm using a 2N4033, and I'm providing 12.3V between the emitter and the collector. For the base, I have a voltage divider of a 100k and a 1k, which provides the base with about 12V. This should cause Vce to be 0, as the voltage difference between Vce and Vbe is under 0.7V. However, when everything is powered on, the Vce is 12V, when it should be zero. Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Added circuit diagram. The SPST is the control mechanism for turning the circuit on and off. The valve is represented by the inductor. The current draw from the valve is 540 mA at 12V. My power supply can supply 2A at 12V.

Comment: You probably are not giving the base enough current, but we need to see a schematic and to know the current draw of the valve coil.

Comment: There is even a nice integrated tool to draw a simple schematic if you don't have any drawn already.

Comment: Thanks  for the comments, schematic added and more information given.

Comment: Where is the valve meant to be connected?

Comment: You have removed your load? :-)

Comment: That circuit is a smoke generator.

Comment: Good try at the protective diode. It should be connected anti-parallel to your load. Could you use a Coil/Inductor symbol for a load?

Comment: Where's the load? When you close the switch the transistor will short the rails. And finally the transistor will explode. Even before that, the LED will burn since you are loading the 12V battery with a single LED (or diode).

Comment: As I stated in the question, the LED was meant to represent the valve. I've since changed it to an inductive load since it was a source of confusion for a few people.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question and for the schematic :-)

With the SPST switch open, the resistive divider settles the base at about 120 mV, which is below the opening voltage of a BJT B-E junction. So the transistor does not conduct from C to E. R2 is too high to have any meaningful effect, you could as well leave it out.

Note that you do not have a resistor in series with the SPST switch. If you close the SPST switch = make it conduct, the circuit between your 12V PSU, the switch and the BJT's B-E junction has no defined current limit. If your 12V PSU is strong enough, it will blow the base connection out of the transistor, or fry the chip, or both.

I suggest that you put a resistor in series with the SPST switch. Check how much current your transistor can sustain. In a randomly chosen datasheet for the commodity 2N4033, I cannot see Ibe(max) specified, but Ic(max) is 1A, so you can probably consider that. Actually much less should be sufficient. To allow for Ic=1A, considering a conservative Hfe=50, you could ballpark that you need to limit the base current to 20 mA. At about 11 V available differential voltage (the B-E junction will clamp at about 0.6 V) the resistor should be 11 / 0.02 = 510 Ohms (a particular standardized value in the series).

EDIT:

See Spehro Pefhany's answer.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the circuit as you stated (new schematic above) but the switch still won't turn off at any point. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've probably blown the transistor and the LED by now, you may need new ones. Unless the LED has a current-limit resistor integrated, always use a resistor in series with an LED, to limit its current to about 20 mA (10 mA would be safer). I.e. for 12V supply, you need about 1k2 in series with the LED. And, the LED goes in series with the transistor's Collector electrode. Do not expect the circuit to work if your transistor just shorts the PSU :-)

Comment: I've replaced the transistor, and I don't have an LED - it was meant as a placeholder for the valve (stated in question), so imagine the valve I described there instead. My valve triggers on when the switch is open every time, but it won't turn off when I close the switch.

Edit: changed the LED in the schematic with a load inductor

Comment: Just addressed your transistor shorting issue : that was my bad haha, I wasn't paying attention when I wired stuff. Newest schematic up. Now the valve won't trigger at all.

Comment: How much current does the valve need to "trigger" ? You could just measure it with an Amper-meter.

Comment: As stated in the question, it's supposed to draw 540mA at 12V.

Comment: Also, the one final touch to your circuit would be: put a diode in parallel with the valve (inductor) and place it such that it is normally reversed (not conducting). Its role is to absorb an inductive spike upon the transistor turning *off*.

Comment: So if your valve does not "trigger", have you tried measuring current through the valve, while it should've triggered?

Comment: It's reading zero current draw

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, the circuit works now! Thank you so much frr, I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: Congrats Yonahel :-)

Answer (score 0):

When the switch is closed, the transistor will be destroyed, with the circuit as shown, as the base current is not externally limited.

R1 and R2 do nothing of value. The 2N4403 is pretty marginal for switching 540mA and you should have a diode across the valve coil or the transistor will be destroyed when it switches off. Since the load is inductive, I think the 2N4403 will be outside the SOA limits and will fail either immediately or after a short time, even if properly driven with ~50mA base current.

This answers your immediate question, but there is not enough information to make helpful suggestions on how to do whatever it is you are trying to do. A MOSFET would be better in this voltage/current range.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at a MOSFET circuit 
And please add a diode in inverse parallel to your inductor to prevent voltage spikes from destroying your components, since inductors can create large spikes when switched off